# how to display the zoom-in view in the standard mode of the large-screen phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

Recently I was asked to adapt to large-screen phones because the standard mode view looks too small on large-screen phones. So I thought of a simple way: display the zoom-in view in the standard mode of the large-screen phone. But i can't find a good way to realize it.
The original idea was to set the currentMode setting of UIScreen, but iOS does not support the creation of external UIScreenMode...

Comment: There is no "quick fix".  If your app is old then simply recompiling with the new Xcode will probably get rid of the "black bars" top and bottom (You need to ensure you are using a launch storyboard, not launch images).  How your UI adapts to the larger screen depends on how it was written.  If it has fixed sizes then you will have to do the hard work of rewriting it to use an adaptive approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a storyboard, use code with frame. You can use masonry, use multipliedBy. If you don’t change anything code and want to directly adapt, that’s unlikely.